# Setting log level is not having any impact in scrapy

Tags: logging, scrapy

I'm running the scrapy crawler using CrawlerProcess as shown below

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
l = logging.getLogger("crawl")

try:
    p = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
   
    crawler = p.create_crawler('my_crawler')
    p.crawl(crawler)
    p.start()
    crawl_stats = crawler.stats.get_stats()
    ...using crawl_stats
except Exception:
    l.exception("Failed to crawl")
```

And my settings.py has following log settings

```
LOG_ENABLED = True
LOG_LEVEL = 'WARNING'
```

When running the crawler scrapy is printing lots of debug messages on console. Setting LOG_LEVEL to 'WARNING' is not having any impact.

Environment:
Scrapy= 2.5.0
Python= 3.8
Debian

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Somehow it is not possible to get project settings automatically without specify.

```
from path.to.your.settings import settings as st
 

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
l = logging.getLogger("crawl")

try:
    crawler_settings = Settings()
    crawler_settings.setmodule(st)
    p = CrawlerProcess(settings=crawler_settings)
    crawler = p.create_crawler('my_crawler')
    p.crawl(crawler)
    p.start()
    crawl_stats = crawler.stats.get_stats()
    ...using crawl_stats
except Exception:
    l.exception("Failed to crawl")
```

It works for me.